How to get partial vertical lines in table?
Consider the following MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.15}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|}
 & $m_1^C$ & $m_2^C$ \\\cline{2-3}
 $m_1^L$ & $\omega_1$ & $\omega_2$ \\\cline{2-3}
 $m_2^L$ & $\omega_3$ & $\omega_4$ \\\cline{2-3}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}

Which produces this output:

I need to get rid of the bits of the vertical lines marked in red (see pic below):

So, how do I get rid of the bits crossed out in red? Or, more generally, how do I obtain partial vertical lines in a table?
I have tried many of the solutions to similar questions available on the site, but I couldn’t make any of them work (and most of them seem overkill for a simple problem like mine).

Use \multicolumn{1}{c}{...} in the cells. But why are you using a tabular and putting every entry in math mode instead of simply using an array in math mode altogether?

You could use the nicematrix package, it has options to set the first row/column outside of the table lines:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.15}
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccc}[hvlines,first-row,first-col]
   & $m_1^C$ & $m_2^C$ \\
   $m_1^L$ & $\omega_1$ & $\omega_2$ \\
   $m_2^L$ & $\omega_3$ & $\omega_4$ \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}

(you could use a NiceMatrix instead of NiceTabular, then you wouldn't need to add $...$ to all cells)

Using tabularx:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.15}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$m_1^C$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$m_2^C$}\\ 
\cline{2-3}
$m_1^L$ & $\omega_1$  & $\omega_2$\\ 
\cline{2-3}
$m_2^L$ & $\omega_3$ & $\omega_4$\\
\cline{2-3}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}


